# Can I get muscle name by using a collider in Unity3d?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

What I would like to do is to get the muscle name of the humanoid after I click on it. The reason to do this is to get body restrictions in a script and apply them at run time. For example, if I try move leg of the humanoid game object, it moves in all directions and it is not what I desire. I would like to restrict and avoid these movements. And also, the body part I'm tying to move seems to move through other body parts. Is there any way to restrict these things through script?

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you use physics to animate stuff or is it hard scripted? do you use hinge joints? It would be good to provide couple of screenshots too to give us a better idea.

Comment: @NikaKasradze I'm moving the body part through script using functions like transform.Rotate() and a slider to get the rotate angle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code but the muscle needs a collider

```
var hit : RaycastHit;                                 
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay ( Input.mousePosition );    
hit = Physics.Raycast (ray, 100);
if (hit && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
{
    Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
}
```

Comment: Also consider the part for adding **restrictions** to body parts.

Comment: Using if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) check before raycasting is better from performance point of view. Also consider using RaycastNonAlloc - http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastNonAlloc.html